# Simple Search Form Tag

Tags: simple-search

I am using this tag pair for a website form. Two issues I have:

1. How do I make certain fields required without using CSS3 or jQuery. Does EE have a native way of doing this?
2. How do I get validation to work on iOS?
3. Are there any better third party form add ons that someone can recommend?

Comment: CSS3? Or do you mean HTML5? You can't use CSS for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can't make fields required.

The more popular search add-ons are [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) and [Solspace Super Search](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/super_search/)

Both of these add-ons have validation built in, as well as obviously many other features you won't find on the native EE search form.